# LaunchedEffect triggering even thought composition should have ended and key changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Compose to build my Android UI.
I have a screen where I want to be able to search for stocks and show them in a LazyColumn. For triggering the API call I'm using a LaunchedEffect like this.

```kotlin
    val stocks = remember { mutableStateListOf<Stock>() }
    var searchText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val hasSearchEnoughChars = searchText.length >= 3

...

    if(hasSearchEnoughChars) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = searchText) {
            delay(500)
            searchStocksForText(searchText) {
                isSearching = false
                wereStocksFound = it.isNotEmpty()
                stocks.clear()
                stocks.addAll(it)
            }
        }
    } else {
        stocks.clear()
    }
```

```
...
    SearchField(
                onValueChanged = {
                    searchText = it
                }
    )
...

private fun SearchField(
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isError: Boolean = false
) {
    var inputText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = inputText,
        onValueChange = {
            inputText = it
            onValueChanged(it)
        },
        ...
    )
}
```

This is how `searchText` is updated.

```
fun searchStocksForText(searchText: String, onDataReceived: (List<Stock>) -> Unit) {
StockApiConnection().getStocksViaSearch(
        query = searchText,
        onSuccess = { onDataReceived(it) },
        onFailure = { onDataReceived(emptyList()) }
    )
}
```

This is the async function which is build on top of a retrofit callback.

So far so good, but I'm experiencing a weird behavior of LaunchedEffect in an edgecase.
When having typed 4 Chars into the Textfield (represented by `searchText`) and erasing 2 of them with a slight delay (probably the `delay(500)` from LaunchedEffect) the stocks will still be fetched for the 3-char-sized searchText and therefore shown in the LazyColumn.

I also already tried using a CoroutineScope, having the `if(hasSearchEnoughChars)`  statement inside of the LaunchedEffect and also aborting the LaunchedEffect / Scope in the else Branch but nothing seems to work. Curiously the API is not called when typing fast, except the last one after 500ms, as intended.

For my understanding LaunchedEffect should cancel the current Coroutine

1. when the Key changes and
2. when the Composable leaves the composition

which should booth be the case but the callback is still triggered.

Is there something I'm missing when handling async callbacks in LaunchedEffect or is my understanding of LaunchedEffect wrong?

Comment: Is `searchStocksForText()` a suspend function or an asynchronous function? It looks asynchronous since it seems to have a callback, and if it is, it's not cancellable by the coroutine being cancelled. Can you show how it is defined? And how is `searchText` being updated?

Comment: @Tenfour04 `searchStocksForText()` is an async API callback based on a Retrofit Callback. I edited my Question to show how `searchText` is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`searchStocksForText()` is an asynchronous function with callback instead of a suspend function, so if the coroutine is cancelled after it has already been fired, it cannot be cancelled and it's callback will still be run. You need to convert it into a suspend function:

```
suspend fun searchStocksForText(searchText: String): List<Stock> = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    StockApiConnection().getStocksViaSearch(
        query = searchText,
        onSuccess = { cont.resume(it) },
        onFailure = { cont.resume(emptyList()) }
    )
}
```

Then you can call the code synchronously in your coroutine, and it will be cancellable appropriately:

```
    if(hasSearchEnoughChars) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = searchText) {
            delay(500)
            val stocks = searchStocksForText(searchText)
            isSearching = false
            wereStocksFound = it.isNotEmpty()
            stocks.clear()
            stocks.addAll(it)
        }
    } else {
        stocks.clear()
    }
```

However, I think using a launched effect for this is kind of convoluted. You might try doing it with a Flow and using `debounce()`. I didn't test this, so beware. Still a newbie to Compose myself, and I'm not sure if the cold flow needs to be stored in a `remember` parameter before you call `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` on it.

```
val searchText = remember { MutableStateFlow("") }
val stocks: State<List<Stock>> = searchText
    .debounce(500)
    .onEach { isSearching = true }
    .map { if (it.length >= 3) searchStocksForText(searchText) else emptyList() }
    .onEach { isSearching = false }
    .collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
val wereStocksFound = stocks.isNotEmpty()
```

---

Side note, beware of using `length >= 3` on your search string. That is completely ignoring code point size.

Comment: Thanks, that was the Problem! My learning: **asysnc callbacks don't work well in combination with LaunchedEffect / Coroutines.** Just one small thing:  ``CancellableContinuation.resume()`` also needs a ``onCancellation`` callback. Also thanks for the additional tipps, I will have a look at them too.